# My recursive program is not returning the smallest element in the tree as intended

Tags: java, recursion, tree

I have a tree and am trying to write a recursive method to find the smallest value in the tree however my method is not returning the smallest element in the tree, my output when I run my program is `Minimum is: 24`. Here is my code:

```
package weekFour;

public class MinTree {

    static int min;

    static Tree tree = new Tree( 24, 
                 new Tree( 45, 
                     null , 
                     new Tree(8, null , null) ) , 
                 new Tree ( 17, 
                     new Tree (74 , null , null ) , 
                     null ) );

    public static void main(String[] args){
    MinTree mt = new MinTree();
    System.out.println("Minimum is: " + mt.findMin(tree, Integer.MAX_VALUE));
    }

    public int findMin(Tree tree, int min){

        if(tree.getVal() < min) {

            min = tree.getVal();
        }

        Tree tree1 = tree.left();
        if (tree1 != null) {
            findMin(tree1, min);
        }

        Tree tree2 = tree.right();
        if (tree2 != null) {
            findMin(tree2, min);
        }

        return min;
    }


}

class Tree {

   private int val;
   private Tree left, right;

   public Tree(int val, Tree left, Tree right){
     this.val = val;
     this.left = left;
     this.right = right;
   }

   public int getVal(){
      return val;
   }

   public Tree left(){
      return left;
   }

   public Tree right(){
      return right;
   }
}
```

Thanks for your time

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your `findMin` method, you don't capture the result of the recursive call...

Change:

```
Tree tree1 = tree.left();
if (tree1 != null) {
    findMin(tree1, min);
}

Tree tree2 = tree.right();
if (tree2 != null) {
    findMin(tree2, min);
}
```

To something like this:

```
Tree tree1 = tree.left();
if (tree1 != null) {
    min = findMin(tree1, min);
}

Tree tree2 = tree.right();
if (tree2 != null) {
    min = findMin(tree2, min);
}
```

Comment: Thanks  for the quick response :)

Answer (score 0):

You local `min` name = static variable's `min` name.

change it to get the right result. or do something like this =>

```
public int findMin(Tree tree, int min){

            if(tree.getVal() < min) {

                MinTree.min = tree.getVal();
            }

            Tree tree1 = tree.left();
            if (tree1 != null) {
                findMin(tree1, MinTree .min);
            }

            Tree tree2 = tree.right();
            if (tree2 != null) {
                findMin(tree2, MinTree .min);
            }

            return help.min;
        }
```